# Simple version of jQuery live function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, live

Is it possible to get anywhere a pure Javascript function for event handler with similar functionality as jQuery's `live()` ? I need to have the ability to attach events to objects not yet created but both jquery-livequery as well as jquery-events sources are not useful due to dependencies on jQuery core.

Comment: Yes,is it possible. Jquery is an lib created in javascript language.
All function in self,can to be rewritten

Comment: Why are you reinventing this wheel?  What's wrong with being dependent on jQuery for this function?

Comment: What method are you using to add new elements to the page? Why can't you wire up the events in the same code that adds the elements?

Comment: @Sparky672 - not everyone wants to add 90kb of script to their page for some fairly simple functionality. Using jQuery has its own issues.

Comment: I know how event delegation works, but I just thought there might be an out of the box ready function concerning cross browser issues etc.  I don't wanna use jQuery and if sbdy thinks it's easy to use any of it's functions independently it just shows he had never seen the source of jQ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Event delegation is quite simple. Take this example:

Markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>Test</p>
</div>

<button id="add">Add new paragraph</button>
```

Script:

```
document.getElementById("container").onclick = function(e) {

    // e.target is the target of the event or "source element"
    alert(e.target.innerHTML);
};

// dynamically adds new paragraph on button click
document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = "a new paragraph";
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(p);
};
```

Since the event handler is attached to the parent, it will work for any future elements inserted.

[**You can try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/RWqrD/1/)

Useful reference:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#target
- http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's called event delegation and has been around longer than jQuery and "live".

"live" works by listening for events on the body or document, then when when an event occurs looks at the event.target to see if it's selector matches one of those stored in a cache. It is quite inefficient, but works OK for some.

A more efficient approach is to add elements you want listeners on to an array, then listen for bubbling events on the lowest common ancestor of the elements you want to delegate events for. The body element is the fallback, but it's the least efficient. When the listener gets an event it's waiting for, check if the event.target is one of the elements in the array and if so, call the related function with the element as *this*.

You can also just store the element id as a property of an object so looking it up is faster if you have lots of elements, or you can register events based on class.

There are a few limitations and foibles (some events bubble in some browsers but not others, and some don't bubble at all), and it can be very inefficient, so use with care.

Comment: +1 for the performance concerns and the word of caution about non-bubbling events and browser implementation inconsistencies.

Comment: There's an interesting article on jQuery's .live extension titled [Why You Should Never Use jQuery Live](http://jupiterit.com/news/why-you-should-never-use-jquery-live). Much of the detail applies to event delegation in general.

Answer (score 1):

I know little of Jquery and your functions. 
You are looking how works with events in javascript?
You can make this:

```
element.addEventListener('onclick', 
function() { 
  //do something
});
```

or

```
element.onclick =
function() { 
  //do something
});
```

the `element` var is an reference of dom document.
check https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM for more details.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is pure JavaScript and OpenSource, so just have a look into the sources, then copy what you need and adapt it.

Comment: +1 Not to mention that it's already cross-browser tested.  I'll never understand why people feel the need to "re-invent the wheel" when it serves no greater purpose.

Comment: I think its good to be curious ;) But on the other hand, dealing with the odds and ends of IE alone would make me sick ;)

Comment: Not very much of jQuery looks like regular DOM manipulation.  It's built in so many layers on it's own mini-platform that it can be downright daunting to figure out what DOM calls actually get made in a relatively simple jQuery operation.  I'm not saying this is bad for jQuery, just that your suggestion is not as easy as one might think with jQuery.  You have to get pretty deep into it before you find it actually calling the DOM and then, what you find is not easy to copy or move out of jQuery because it uses so much of it's own platform.  @karim79's answer is much more helpful.

Comment: -1 for a lazy post, +1 for jfriend's comment. You can't just cut bits out of jQuery, it is so tightly interwoven with itself that chasing down exactly what a simple function does is often laborious and not worth the effort most of the time.